# Two similar if-conditions in one

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, if-statement

In a Javascript function I have two conditions that are similar in their structure. I wonder if you could combine them together into one. The code is from my random  cryptographically secure numbers/chars generator.
Here's a snippet from the Java script code:

```
function randomString(length, charset, allowRandomSourceFallback) {
    var i,
        result = "";

    // First we're going to try to use a built-in CSPRNG
    if (window.crypto && window.crypto.getRandomValues) {
        values = new Uint32Array(length);
        window.crypto.getRandomValues(values);

        for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            result += charset[values[i] % charset.length];
        }
    }
    // IE calls it msCrypto (built-in CSPRNG)
    else if (window.msCrypto && window.msCrypto.getRandomValues) {
        values = new Uint32Array(length);
        window.msCrypto.getRandomValues(values);

        for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            result += charset[values[i] % charset.length];
        }
    }
    // -> No built-in functionality -> use the function Math.random()
    else {
        for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            result += charset[Math.floor(Math.random() * charset.length)];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is soliciting improvements for working code. For code that is working, without errors, see http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @p.s.w.g: You didn't understand my question.... should I paste false code!?

Comment: @John, _"it would be nice if you make corrections/improvements"_ this suggests you are looking for a peer review of your code, and not that you actually have a problem with the current code, as such it is offtopic. Peer review questions belong on codereview, like p.s.w.g's close message mentions.

Comment: See this question on the Code Review meta: [How is this site different from Stack Overflow?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/138/how-is-this-site-different-from-stack-overflow)

Comment: stay loose, removed sentence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not check what is available and then use it:

```
var availableCrypto = window.crypto || window.msCrypto; // will get whatever is available
```

then use it like so:

```
availableCrypto.getRandomValues(values);
```

Here you go:

```
function randomString(length, charset, allowRandomSourceFallback) {
    var i,
        result = "",
        availableCrypto = window.crypto || window.msCrypto;

    // First we're going to try to use a built-in CSPRNG
    if (availableCrypto && availableCrypto.getRandomValues) {
        values = new Uint32Array(length);
        availableCrypto.getRandomValues(values);

        for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            result += charset[values[i] % charset.length];
        }
    }
    // -> No built-in functionality -> use the function Math.random()
    else {
        for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            result += charset[Math.floor(Math.random() * charset.length)];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: +1 The only thing you'd want to do is add an if statement in case `availableCrypto` is null.

Comment: @EthanBrown Definitely.. this is just to guide him how 2 club 2 ifs into 1.. he surly needs to take care of such things :)

Comment: @LuckySoni: Can you please paste the full code? sorry, I don't get it -.-

Answer (score 1):

instead of making them together, declare only one crypto function like below

```
var crypto = null;
if (window.crypto && window.crypto.getRandomValues) {
        crypto = window.crypto;        
    }
    // IE calls it msCrypto (built-in CSPRNG)
    else if (window.msCrypto && window.msCrypto.getRandomValues) {
        crypto = window.msCrypto ;
    }

if(crypto != null){
        values = new Uint32Array(length);
        crypto.getRandomValues(values);

        for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            result += charset[values[i] % charset.length];
        }
}
    else {
        for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            result += charset[Math.floor(Math.random() * charset.length)];
        }
    }
    return result;
```